# Creating a Table to cater and calculate SUMPRODUCT equivalent

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following table in sql as per below. Users capture for each KPIID an actual an budget for each period.

From this table i need to calculate a similar result as which i have done in Excel using SUMPRODUCT, but i dont know what the equivalent sql query would look like to obtain these results.

[image: EXAMPLE SQL]

I would like to obtain a result like this which i have made an example in excel
[image: RESULT]

Comment: Presenting your data in Excel format is not so helpful.  My guess is that any remotely sane table design and a basic query will get you want you want.

Comment: I presented my data in excel since i have no  table in place as yet. Hence why im here asking which will be the best way to structure it, so that i can query it  correctly. Since my data can span over a a couple of periods.

Comment: What is the relationship/meaning between `Actual_1`, `Actual_2` etc. and the actual columns in your SQL table?

Comment: Actual_1 =  SELECT Actual from KPI_actbud Where KPIID = 1 and Year = 2017 and period =1  and then for Actual_2 = SELECT Actual from KPI_actbud Where KPIID = 2 and Year = 2017 and period = 1; So i assume period and year is self explanatory

Comment: So to calculate Actual_4 for Period 3 how will i do this using my sql table?

Comment: I still don't see an clean way of doing this.  You might have been better off just showing the input SQL table along with the expected output table.  Leave Excel out of this; it will only confuse things.

Comment: OK, i have restructured ho i asked my question, hopefully this is more clear

Comment: This must be difficult, i will research it a bit then thanks .